# Concatenate certain values according to their keys using case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

I want to know how to concatenate values for certain keys. Example data:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | Alex |
| 1 | status | single |
| 1 | age | 21 |
| 1 | income | 20K |
| 1 | hight | 85 |
| 2 | name | David |
| 2 | status | single |
| 2 | age | 23 |
| 2 | income | 10K |
| 2 | hight | 75 |

I try to concatenate just three keys `Alex,21,85` per id.

So I have something similar to that:

```
select case
    when something then null
    else concat(name.value, age.value, hight.value)
end
from names
```

So what should be in the concat in order to get this values? I don't need to show the keys but just the values combined `Alex,21,85` or `David,23,75` each time the values are different for each id so it can't be hardcoded.

Comment: Post sample data.

Comment: @Salman A I added an example data...just table with 2 colums: numbers and their names

Comment: @Salman A yes the keys are not changing. Their values are changing. each time row_id with the same key and different value

Comment: @salman A I gave a better example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a dynamic list of keys such as `name, age, hight` and you want to display those values per user.

You need to use aggregation and `string_agg`:

```
select id, string_agg(
    "value", ','
) within group (order by charindex(',' + "key" + ',', ',name,age,hight,')) as csv
from t
where "key" in ('name', 'age', 'hight')
group by id
```

Comment: I don't use MySQL so it doesn't recognized group_concat

Comment: also listagg is not recognized as build in function\= it has string_agg

Comment: @Salaman A I'm using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

DDL

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    p_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    p_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO person (p_name) VALUES ("Alex"), ("David"), ("Kate"), ("Lisa"), ("Maya");
```

The query you need. There are more options available so you might wanna read on [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p_name SEPARATOR ', ') as "string"
FROM person
WHERE p_id IN (2, 4, 5);
```

Expected output:

| string |
| --- |
| David, Lisa, Maya |